# converting special characters to hex in python

Tags: python, hex, special-characters

i have an incoming UDP packet that goes like : 2%W2R.ÃR.Â\Îç½Ý8_5©"ÿ­

I want to convert this to hex in python. I have tried binascii functions but I get the error odd length string.

Any suggestions on converting this to hex?

Thank you in advance.
-VJ

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "hkfhfksadhfskadl"
a.encode("hex")
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> a = 'aljsd;fkaj;'
>>> binascii.hexlify(a)
'616c6a73643b666b616a3b3b6b666a7177657234'
```

If you get error, please post both code and error message here.